# Dynamic responsive grid with masonry

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-masonry

I want to have a 2-column page with blocks, that can be "opened" after a click, see http://jsfiddle.net/pdjpdwLe/2/.

```
.item {
   float: left;
   width: 50%;
   height: 100px;
   margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.item.open {
   height: 300px;
}
```

Currently I'm using masonry, which is working really well, but I would like to prevent the items from changing the columns. For example if I click on the top left block, it expands, but the block below shifts to the right column.

```
$("#masonry").masonry({
    itemSelector: ".item"
});

$(".item").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("open");

    $("#masonry").masonry({
        itemSelector: ".item"
    });
});
```

Is it possible to do it that the blocks will always move only downwards within the column?

The masonry plugin doesn't have to be used, I understand that there can be some inner logic for rearranging the blocks, that cannot be changed.